# How do I create a map table in postgresql? I am using integer values from 0 to 5 and the mapping needs to be in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, mapping, pgadmin

For example I have a table A, I am using id values from 0 to 5. I need another map table B which has the following structure (only 2 columns with the description of each integer value)

0 --> id_description_0

1 --> id_description_1

2 --> id_description_2

3 --> id_description_3

4 --> id_description_4

5 --> id_description_5

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like this?

```
create table b as
    select 0 as a_id, 'id_description_0' as description union all
    select 1 as a_id, 'id_description_1' as description union all
    select 2 as a_id, 'id_description_2' as description union all
    select 3 as a_id, 'id_description_3' as description union all
    select 4 as a_id, 'id_description_4' as description union all
    select 5 as a_id, 'id_description_5' as description;
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and creating a table b and inserting the integer values from 0 to 5 and description for each integer? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: What I meant to ask is, is there any specific kind of mapping table in Postgresql, if yes how do I create it and link with the actual table ? I didnt find any documentation on that

Comment: @Sam . . . There are tables.  There are not "types" of tables (based on data).  I mean, there are variations such as partitioned tables but they refer to how the data is stored.

Comment: So there is nothing particular like a "map table". If you create a table and use it just for mapping, you can call it a map table but in the end its just a normal table right? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Sam . . . Exactly.